# using cucumber with shared driver

Tags: java, webdriver, cucumber

I have a basic question. Wondering how the cucumber runner initiating shared driver??

I have not seen anywhere instructing the cucumber to initiate the shared driver class. wondering, how is this framework working???

I have commented out the shared driver class, then when i execute cucumber runner, i see an exception that cucumber is initiating the pico container and this pico container is looking for shared driver class and finally since that class is not found, it is giving class not found exception.

Can some one explain me - how is this working. Cucumber with shared driver. 
Pls let me know if you need any more details. I will share. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this class](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/picocontainer/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/java/picocontainer/PicoFactory.java) which searches in the classpath for any dependency your app needs.

This class basically iterates over all the constructors in a 'recursive' way to resolve all the dependencies by adding them to `PicoContainer`. If one of them is not found (like in this case the Shared Driver) it throws an exception.

Then you can see in [this class](https://github.com/picocontainer/PicoContainer2/blob/master/pico/container/src/java/org/picocontainer/injectors/ConstructorInjector.java) how the dependencies are injected.

Comment: Thank you alayor for your time! Appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: How does accepting an answer work? for more information